# Digitally signed macro is being disabled despite assigning self-signed certificate

Tags: vba, outlook, certificate

I have created a self-signed digital certificate for a macro I have built, using the selfcert.exe application in the Microsoft Office directory. I apply the certificate and then close Outlook - from what I understand, I should get a security prompt upon re-opening Outlook that allows an option for 'Enable all macros by this publisher'.

I never get this prompt, and when trying to run the macro, I get a message that it is disabled - despite having the macro security settings set to **'Notifications for digitally signed macros, all other macros disabled'**.

Why doesn't Outlook think that the macro is digitally signed? It is visible if you navigate to Tools -> Digital Signature on VBA.

I suspected it might be something to do with the certificate not being listed as a 'Trusted Publisher', but I have tried copying the certificate over to the Trusted Publishers/Trusted Root certificate directories under certmgr ('Manage user certificates' in Start menu) and this hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Do you have Inactive Add-ins?

Comment: @0m3r I did have one, but removing it hasn't made a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Let me know if your issue is solved, I also have same issue with macro, thanks.